# InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile$1 is not implementing InputStreamStatistics

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have just migrated my libraries so that my code is now using the new Apache POI5.0 instead of POI4.12. I am using POI to build an Excel file from scratch with data retrieved from my database.
The code was working fine but now, when my code is writing the contents, I receive an exception.
I am using commons-compress-1.20 which is the library released with Apache POI5.0.

```
[err] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile$1 is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
[err]   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.<init>(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:65)
[err]   at [internal classes]
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of Apache Commons Compress on your classpath, can you remove the old one and leave just the one that Apache POI uses?

Comment: did we get an answer here ? I am curious as I am also getting a similar error
- 
InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile$1 is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
        at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.loadFromResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:49)

Comment: @Sudhakar Singh: I doubt someone will be able to answer this properly as the stacktrace is not complete. The stacktrace tells that **something** tries using the constructor of  `ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream` and hand over an `InputStream`which not implements `InputStreamStatistics`. But the constructor of  `ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream` checks whether  the given `InputStream` is instanceof `InputStreamStatistics` and throws that error if not. So we would need to know **what** tries using the constructor with a wrong `InputStream`.

Comment: As a guess, as @Gagravarr told already, there must be an old version of `org.apache.commons`-> `commons-compress` in class path where `ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipArchiveEntry ze)` returns an `InputStream` which not  implements `InputStreamStatistics`. That would must be a  `commons-compress`  version lower than or equal `1.16`. So check your class path.

Comment: @GNF can you provide a small [mre] to reproduce the message please? Could help to find a solution. Best WITH your dependencies specified.

Comment: I will never understand why people open questions or even spend reputation points for a bounty on other people's ones, but then are unwilling to walk the last mile and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Instead, they do nothing and let the question stay unanswered or let the bounty expire due to their own inactivity and lack of cooperation. Is that meant to yield helpful answers? I just don't get it. Folks, if you are unable to create an MCVE, stop calling yourselves software developers! _(Sorry for the rant.)_

Comment: I did not receive any answers (except for the Gagravarr suggestion) until this thread has come back to live **14 months** later.
I cannot remember now if / how I solved this problem. I agree with Gagravarr that this might have been a library conflict. Due to time constrains in the project and taking into account that POI 5.x did not provide any new features which were needed,  I think I just switched back to POI 4.x.

Comment: It would not have taken 14 months but possibly less than 14 hours to receive an answer, if you simply had asked your question the right way.  My remarks from above also went to the person opening the bounty, drawing attention to this old question, but who also did nothing whatsoever to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been facing this problem every time I tried to upgrade to a new Apache POI release and used to forget about it because of not having the time to take care of it.
I had tried with multiple releases of Apache Common Compress (1.18 - 1.22). Same results.

The other day (two years since my first try and 18 months after posting my question) I finally found a useful suggestion for solving my problem. I am posting it here in case someone might find it useful.
The suggestion was using the piece of code below to find which library contained the code I was trying to use.

```
String s = <class>.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

So, in my case I wrote:

```
String s = org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

And the output was:

```
file:/C:/IBM/lib/com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot_1.0.20.jar
```

My WebSphere Liberty server had its own version of the library and that was the one in use.

Once I found the problem it was just a case of changing the order on which the libraries were loaded (parentLast).

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this could be happening, as mentioned in the comments.

There could be a version conflict. Specifically you have version <= 1.6 of Apache commons-compress alongside >= 5 of Apache POI which are not compatible. To solve this, you will need to change your classpath - if you're using Maven then use `mvn dependency:tree` and if Gradle then use `gradle dependencies`.

You don't know where the call to the constructor is coming from because (probably) the application server Liberty is removing some of them. You can get the full stacktrace from `messages.log` and then you can see the full cause which could poentially be another class calling the `ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream` constructor with another InputStream that doesn't implement `InputStreamStatistics`. I would guess that this is less likely than the simple version conflict mentioned above.